# Looking for PubSub messaging for end-clients on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, messaging, publish-subscribe, clients

Does AWS offer a service for real-time publish&subscribe messaging for end clients? (web, mobile, desktop).
I'm looking for something that is topic based, optionally with a statfull model of data, where clients can subscribe to topics, receive data published on these topics at real time, etc.
(similar to what Google Firebase offers).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [**Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html) provides:

- Topic creation
- Publishing of messages to the topic
- Subscription to a topic via:

  - Email
  - HTTP/S endpoint (effectively, a REST call)
  - SMS
  - Sending to an Amazon SQS queue
  - Triggering an AWS Lambda function
  - Sending mobile notifications (iOS, Android, Baidu, Windows mobile, Windows desktop, Mac desktop)